# How to determine if java package is installed?

Tags: java, jar, package

I am trying to compile this sample Java class (on Centos 6)

https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/kafka-streams/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java

The first error I get is

```
error: package org.apache.kafka.common.serialization does not exist
```

How do I determine if the relevant packages (jar files) are indeed installed on the machine? I tried to include the relevant path (I guessed) via the -cp option but the class fails to compile.

Tried to used find, but not sure what I should look for.

Any leads highly appreciated.

Why is this not a duplicate:
The "other" question is generic and is related to package not specified in the class being compiled. My question is about determining the location of packages NEEDED by my class.

Comment: That project uses maven to manage its dependencies, so building it with Maven should do the trick.

Comment: If you look at the corresponding pom.xml (https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/kafka-streams/blob/master/pom.xml) it shows you all required packages.

Comment: pardon my Java ignorance. @MarkRotteveel is it not possible to build without Maven? Trying to avoid going down rabbit holes of understanding Maven and POM files.

Comment: Technically yes, but then you'd have to manually trawl the pom file to know which dependencies you need to add, download them and specify your own classpath. Exactly what a pom file is there to avoid. Note that most IDEs support importing POM files and do all the heavy lifting for you.